# Set message for duplicate value pandas

Tags: python, pandas

i have df like this

```
   A   B 
0  1   ABC
1  2   XYX
2  1   RTC
3  3   fds
4  2   rtv
5  4   rtoc
```

and i want like this

```
    A   B     message
0  1   ABC     
1  2   XYX    
2  1   RTC     Duplicated 
3  3   fds     
4  2   rtv     Duplicated
5  4   rtoc
```

if Column A value is duplicated then set the message duplicated in second occurrence.

Comment: Only for second occurrence? what if there are third occurrence?

Answer (score 4):

###### all duplicates:

Use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) and [`duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html):

```
df['message'] = np.where(df['A'].duplicated(), 'Duplicated', '')
```

output:

```
   A     B     message
0  1   ABC            
1  2   XYX            
2  1   RTC  Duplicated
3  3   fds            
4  2   rtv  Duplicated
5  4  rtoc
```

###### only for the SECOND occurrence:

Use [`groupby`+`cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
df['message'] = np.where(df.groupby('A').cumcount().eq(1), 'Duplicated', '')
```

example:

```
   A                  B     message
0  1   first occurrence            
1  2                XYX            
2  1  second occurrence  Duplicated
3  1   third occurrence            
4  3                fds            
5  2                rtv  Duplicated
6  4               rtoc
```

Comment: This code set 'Duplicated' value for not only second duplicated, but also for their, fourth, fifth...

Comment: @SangkeunPark not sure this is a literal requirement, but easy enough to do (see update)

Comment: Nice information. Thanks. I voted up